# Missing file in the ActionLib Intermediate Tutorial

Tags: ros, actionlib-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I was going through the tutorials on the ActionLib, when I recognized a missing file (description) on the `Averaging Action`.
In the code explanation on the tutorial page (http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionClient%28Threaded%29#The_Code_Explained it says

> [...] This includes action message generated from the Averaging.action file show above. This is a header generated automatically from the AveragingAction.msg file. [...]

, but there actually isn't any Averaging.action file shown on the page or previous pages. Also, the linked AveragingAction.msg (http://www.ros.org/doc/api/actionlib_tutorials/html/msg/AveragingAction.html) isn't existing.

I worked around this with an improvised Averaging.action like this:

```
#goal
int32 samples
---
#result
int32 average
int32 samplecount
int32 stddeviation
---
#feedback
int32 samplenumber
int32 currentaverage
int32 currentstddeviation
```

but I am not sure if it will work semantically correctly when I proceed with the tutorial.

Could someone please update this?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128911/missing-file-in-the-actionlib-intermediate-tutorial/) by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Averaging.action file is available in the actionlib_tutorial source on github: https://github.com/ros/common_tutorials/blob/hydro-devel/actionlib_tutorials/action/Averaging.action

It looks like the underlying problem here is that the common_tutorials package isn't in the documentation indexer in hyrdo. I've submitted https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/3086 to fix this. Once it's accepted, it should generate the missing documentation within a week or so.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on 2014-02-13**:
Thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [bnm-rc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11866/bnm-rc/) on 2014-02-13**:
I just found the mistake: It's all online, but it's not visible if Javascript is enabled. See the first site of the tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28GoalCallbackMethod%29
It's cut off if Javascript is enabled.
Maybe this is due to it seems to be outdated and nobody has had the time to update it. Event though, it would be worth mentioning for those who'd like to do the tutorial ;)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-13**:
It looks like there was no version of that tutorial specified for hydro or indigo, but it was available for older version of ROS. Fixed.